# How do I create a BigQuery view that uses a user-defined function?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to create a BigQuery view that uses a query which invokes a [user-defined function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions).  How do I tell BigQuery where to find the code files for the UDF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Views can reference UDF resources stored in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), inline code blobs, or local files (contents will be loaded into inline code blobs).

To create a view with a UDF using the BigQuery UI, just fill out the UDF resources as you would when running the query normally, and save as a view.  (In other words, no special actions are required).

To specify these during view creation from the command-line client, use the --view_udf_resource flag:

```
bq mk --view="SELECT foo FROM myUdf(table)" \
  --view_udf_resource="gs://my-bucket/my-code.js"
```

In the above example, `gs://my-bucket/my-code.js` would contain the definition for `myUdf()`.  You can provide multiple `--view_udf_resources` flags if you need to reference multiple code files in your view query.

You may specify gs:// URIs or local files.  If you specify a local file, then the code will be read once and packed into an inline code resource.

Via the API, this is a repeated field named `userDefinedFunctionResources`.  It is a sibling of the `query` field that contains the view SQL.

Comment: Hello, can you provide an example of an inline UDF in a view, please?

Comment: By inline UDF, do you mean the deprecated js(...) syntax?

Comment: I meant CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ...I have contacted Google Support though and they told me it's not possible to have inline temporary UDFs in Views.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  That's not currently supported; I'd suggest opening an feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0 to track it

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761445/is-view-udf-resource-broken), the approach in this answer only works for Legacy SQL, not Standard SQL. This matches my experiences today.