# Is "--view_udf_resource" broken?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to reference a UDF inside a View. According to BigQuery documentation ('*bq help mk*') and to this post [How do I create a BigQuery view that uses a user-defined function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167356/how-do-i-create-a-bigquery-view-that-uses-a-user-defined-function), it is possible to do it with the "*--view_udf_resource*" syntax.

However, when I try it I get the following error:

```
# gsutil cat gs://mybucket/bar.js
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetWord() AS ('fire');

# bq mk --nouse_legacy_sql --view_udf_resource="gs://mybucket/bar2.js" --view="SELECT 1 as one, GetWord() as myvalue" mydataset.myfoo
Error in query string: Function not found: GetWord at [1:18]
```

I have also tried it with the Java API and I get the same error:

```
   public void foo(){
        final String viewQuery = "#standardSQL\n SELECT 1 as one, GetWord() as myvalue";

        UserDefinedFunction userDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction.inline("CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetWord() AS ('fire');");

        ViewDefinition tableDefinition = ViewDefinition.newBuilder(viewQuery)
                .setUserDefinedFunctions(userDefinedFunction)
                .build();
        TableId viewTableId = TableId.of(projectName, dataSetName, "foobar");
        final TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder(viewTableId, tableDefinition).build();

        bigQuery.create(tableInfo);
    }

com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Function not found: GetWord at [2:19]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is the Google's documentation misleading and it is not possible to reference any custom UDF from a View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (currently) create a view using standard SQL that uses UDFs. You need to have all of the logic be inline as part of the query itself, and the post that you are looking at is about JavaScript UDFs using legacy SQL. There is an [open feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905921) to support permanent registration of UDFs, however, which would enable you to reference UDFs from views.

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure that this post and the Google documentation were only referring to the "Legacy mode".